# Sorting mixed numbers and letters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sorting, natural-sort

i am trying to do kind of like an advanced sort...
my fields are something like

```
315122-111-7.5
315122-111-8
315122-001-7.5
315122-111-8.5
315122-001-8
315122-001-9
3151-BLK-7
3151-BLK-7.5
3151-BLK-9
```

i am trying to find a way to sort them like so

```
315122-001-7.5
315122-001-8
315122-001-9
315122-111-7.5
315122-111-8
315122-111-8.5
3151-BLK-7
3151-BLK-7.5
3151-BLK-9
```

basically i would want the sorted by  readable number and letters...

any ideas on how to sort such a list?

Comment: I would create a view, or calculated columns to break up your fields how you need then sort by that combination of columns. from your example, I can't tell exacly how you're expecting the sort to go.

Comment: i do not know if that would work because the fields do not follow any sort of convention

Comment: a field or collection that doesn't follow convention, to me, doesn't sound like it's machine-sortable.

Comment: What is the rule for sorting the first part of the field (i.e. the 3151222, 3151 part)?

Comment: Maybe show an other example. I added your initial list in a List(Of String) and .Sort() the list and the output was the same as the one you want. Based on your example, seems like the default sort already does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend implementing a [custom comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) in the .Net side. Then possibly using some Regex to determine the different hyphen separated fields. It's hard to say whether or not the performance would be good though given that it's using Regex.

I don't have any clue how you would do this complicated of a sort in sql server.

Comment: yea i am working on something like that.. but like you said... its rather complex

Comment: the issue is they are not always hypen seperated sometimes i may get 315122-111-11.5E 315122-111-11.5EE or 315122-111-11.5D.. like i said there is not set convention...

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new field that is the amalgamation of the fields you want to sort by. Then you  sort on the amalgamated field, giving you what you want.

You don't actually have to create a field in your source tables to do this. You can create a view, and have the view create the new "sorting" column by selecting the fields and appending them together under your navigation/sorting column name.

I do something very similar from code to create a unique navigation column.

Examples of how to create this unique sort column using a simple top 100 select:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
[ Column1ToBeSorted ], 
[ Column2ToBeSorted ], 
[ Column3 ], 
[ Column4 ], 
[ Column5 ],
( [ Column1ToBeSorted ] + '-' + [ Column2ToBeSorted] ) AS "NavigationKey" 
FROM [dbo].[ SourceTable ] 
ORDER BY [NavigationKey] ASC
```

You can append as many columns as you need. You just need to be consistent.

Simple character fields like varchar and  nvarchar are trivial to use in this manner.

Sorting numeric fields can be a bit tricky. If you want that column to sort as "1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 21, 22, 23, 32, 33, 41, 42" and not as "1, 11, 12, 2, 21, 22, 23, 3, 32, 33, 4, 41, 42", then you end up having to do a padding and substring trick. Just makes the statement a bit more complicated, but not impossible. If you don't care if your numeric column is sorted arithmetically, just that its sorted (ie, string sorting), then you can leave it as a simple string.

Sorting dates (datetime, smalldatetime, etc) requires you casting the date to string, and specifying a conversion type that makes sense to your needs.

Non-fixed point numerics (floats) will probably require you to format/cast to a max width you find suitable to your needs.

It will make queries slower, due to the sorted "NavigationKey" column being constructed. Remember, the server will have to rebuild it any time a row is added, deleted, or a column chosen for sort participating changes. This is why I suggested you create a view--- as you can then skip having the sorted navigation column being built if you don't need it.

As I've said, I do this all from my C# code on the client side, but I could scrape an example of a create view if you need help translating a select statement into a create view statement.